# how can i use other application preference

Tags: android

how can i access other application preference screen implementation from my application by changing in the preference screen layout using intent or something. is it possible to get the implementation of preference why because we have to change the layout according the preference value

please help me on this.

Regards
Thilag.

Comment: if done some changes in my awnser, hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

i do it once with a sharedUserID, you have to give both applications the same SharedID in the `Manifest.xml`

set the sharedUserID in both `Manifest.xml`, set it like in this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)

your code should look like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = con.getSharedPreferences("PrefsFromOtherApk",Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putBoolean("SomeBoolValue", true);
            edit.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. could you please give some details about the implementations